# TypeScript decorators, getting constructor argument types and injection

Tags: typescript, decorator, ecmascript-2016

Suppose you have a class like this with the `Router` decorator attached to it.

```
@Router
class AuthRouter {

    constructor(private cacheService: CacheService) {}
}
```

How do I get the constructor parameter types from within the `Router` decorator? Assume we have stored a singleton of `CacheService` that we can access if we knew the class name "CacheService".

```
function Router(target) {

    // somehow get the constructor class name
    const dependencyNames = 'CacheService' // an array if multiple args in constructor

    // getSingleton is a function that will retrieve
    // a singleton of the requested class / object
    return new target(getSingleton(dependencyNames))
}
```

So whenever we use `AuthRouter`, it will have `CacheService` already injected into it.

Comment: That would've work with other languages like C# using Reflection, which allows to access all the types during run-time. But TypeScript is different. It does not include types information into the run-time, thus types cannot be used during it.
Solution you could try is RegExping `target.toString()` for the args **names**, and then do the singleton injection

Comment: Take a look at the [parameter decorator example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators), they do something like that, but I'm not sure if that will work with a constructor. But it seems that you're missing the point of class decorators. It shouldn't return an instance of the class, if you return then it must be a constructor function.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I understand, I was just fiddling around with decorators to understand how they work. I was wondering how `Angular` does this internally. Is returning a new constructor simply a design principle of `Decorators` or would it have "negative" side effects?

Comment: @jevgenig I was hoping this would be possible by using the `reflect-metadata` library.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You can choose not to return anything from the decorator function, but if you do it needs to be a constructor function. What negative side effects?

Comment: @NitzanTomer what I'm asking is do we really have to return a `constructor` of the class, or is this just suggested by the `Decorator` concept in general(also in `python`)? The thing is that the code above is working as intended, even if I'm returning an instance of the class instead of a new constructor.

Comment: The class decorator will only be called once per decorated class. It won't be called everytime a `new AuthRouter()` is invoked.  I doubt that your code really works as you intend it to

Comment: @NitzanTomer I do not create a new instance every time, in my example, instead of doing something like `router.use('/auth', new AuthRouter())`, I simply do `router.use('/auth', <any>AuthRouter)` <- note that I'm not re-instantiating the decorated class. Thanks for the help, I decided not to go this way and have found something more appealing with decorators

Comment: If you use `--emitDecoratorMetadata` you can use the `Reflect` API to access a rough list of parameter "types". They are not really types though and you should be wary of relying on this mechanism.

Answer (score 9):

```
import 'reflect-metadata'

function Router(target) {
    const types = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target);
    // return a modified constructor
}
```

Note that you are calling getMetadata with no third param. `types` will be array of the constructor parameters. `types[0].name === 'CacheService'` in your case.